# Como atualizar dados de uma tabela somente se os valores novos forem diferentes dos atuais?

Tags: php, mysql, json, sql-update

Como posso fazer um UPDATE somente se os dados enviados forem diferentes dos dados armazenados?

Estou com  o seguinte:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';



$cod_oferta = $_GET['cod_oferta'];
//$cod_categoria_com = $_GET['cod_categoria_com'];
$titulo_promocao = utf8_decode($_GET['titulo_promocao']);
$descricao = utf8_decode($_GET['descricao']);
$igredientes = utf8_decode($_GET['igredientes']);
//$foto = $_GET['foto'];
$valor_sem_desconto = $_GET['valor_sem_desconto'];
$valor_com_desconto = $_GET['valor_com_desconto'];
$validade = $_GET['validade'];

$validade_date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($validade));

$estoque = $_GET['estoque'];
//$cod_fornecedor = $_GET['cod_fornecedor'];
//$cod_categoria = $_GET['cod_categoria'];
$imagem = $_GET['imagem'];
$desconto = $_GET['desconto'];


$query=" UPDATE cadastra_oferta SET titulo_promocao='$titulo_promocao', descricao='$descricao', foto='$imagem', valor_sem_desconto='$valor_sem_desconto', valor_com_desconto='$valor_com_desconto', desconto='$desconto', validade_oferta='$validade_date', igredientes='$igredientes', qtd_estoque='$estoque' 
WHERE cod_oferta='$cod_oferta' ";

        if($con->query($query) === TRUE)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
?>
```

Que atualiza até se estiver em branco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um SELECT antes.

Ex.:

```
$verifica = mysql_query("SELECT cod_oferta, titulo FROM cadastra_oferta WHERE cod_oferta = '$cod_oferta' and titulo = '$titulo'") or die(mysql_error()); if(mysql_num_rows != 0){echo "Informações repetidas";} else {

$insere = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cadastra_oferta (cod_oferta, titulo) VALUES ('$cod_oferta', '$titulo')") or die(mysql_error());

if($insere) {echo "Sucesso ao cadastrar";} else {echo "Erro.";}

}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado @Anderson.

Comment: Valeu amigo.
 Só não esquece de dar um preg_replace nessas variáveis aí, amigo, para evitar SQL Injection.
Ex.:




    $decimal = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]*/","", $_POST['decimal']); 


no ex. acima aceita números decimais. Blz?

Comment: Só um adendo para quem pretende usar o código da resposta: troque o mysql_query (Que já foi até removido no PHP 7) por mysqli_query ou o equivalente em PDO,

Answer (score 4):

O MySQL **não atualiza** se os valores forem iguais, segundo a própria documentação:

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.

[Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

---

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabela` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    INDEX `ID_AUTO_INCREMENT` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

Supondo que faça um:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(`name`, `date`) VALUES ("Inkeliz", "1999-12-12 00:00:00")
```

Ele iria salvar:

```
1 | Inkeliz | 1999-12-12 00:00:00
```

Se você executar:

```
UPDATE tabela SET name = 'Inkeliz' WHERE id = 1;
```

Pode verificar que não irá afetar nenhuma linha:

```
/* Registros afetados: 0 */
```

Quando executar um `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 1
```

Irá retornar:

```
1 | Inkeliz | 1999-12-12 00:00:00
```

Observe que permanece inalterado, nem sequer o `date` será atualizado, lembre-se que está com `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Isto ocorre porque o valor de `name` salvo já é igual ao valor que quer atualizar.

Se executar agora um `name` diferente e posteriormente um `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE tabela SET name = 'zileknI' WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 1;
```

Irá retornar:

```
1 | zileknI | 2017-05-11 21:07:08
```

Neste caso o UPDATE funcionou pois definiu um valor diferente do que já havia no banco de dados, isto irá atualizar o `date` que visualmente permite saber que funcionou.